# Arrangement Markers Hack

Tags: logic-pro-x

I am working with Logic Pro X and using arrangement markers. As you probably know, when you use these, you can assign a marker to a section of your track (call it something original like 'chorus') then if you copy the arrangement marker and place it somewhere else in your track, it will copy all the regions underneath it, effectively repeating that section of the song.

If you needed that explanation, you probably won't be able to help me, but I put it there, in case there is something basic I am misunderstanding about the feature.

What I want to accomplish seems to me to be pretty straightforward and logical - and it seems to me that I program called ''logic'' should do logical things. I have, however, been unable to easily accomplish what I am trying to.

Here is the problem I have:

I have, besides all the tracks in my project in which I am working on, a track that I use as a guide. This track contains an original recording that I am trying to emulate. I need this track to remain intact for the whole project because it is a guide. But I would like to still be able to use the arrangement markers to move all other tracks in one go. Obviously, if I try to move these markers, it will slice the original track as well and move it with the rest completely messing up my guide track. I have tried ''locking'' the track which you would have thought would be understood by Logic as: ''please don't slice up this track'', but nope, Logic slices away.

Is there anyway to achieve what I am trying to do or should I just renounce to using arrangement markers because no one at Logic thought that someone would want to use a guide track?

Thanks

d